# woocommerce function to get svg code product icon

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have add a new field via admin panel in products **product_icon**

[image: field content image]

where I put an SVG icon code. I need to use this SVG plugin. I have put into `woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php` new function.

```
public function get_icon( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_prop( 'icon', $context );
}
```

when I put it into a while loop where I have list products name, prices, etc new function `get_icon()` I have null. In SQL post meta meta key is ok "product_icon" for a correct product with the correct content (SVG code)

My listing Code:

```
<?php
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
        ?>
        <div class="eb-woo-products-col">
            <?php if ( 'grid' === $layout && 'grid-preset-3' === $gridPreset ) { ?>
            <div class="producttabwhite eb-woo-product">
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="producttabblue eb-woo-product">
            <?php } ?>

            <div id="mydiv" class="eb-woo-product-image-wrapper" style="margin-top:2.5rem;margin-right:1.25rem;">
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product->get_image( 'woocommerce_thumbnail' ) ); ?>

                <?php if ( 'grid' === $layout ) { ?>
                <div class="eb-woo-product-overlay">
                    <div class="eb-woo-product-button-list">
                        <?php // woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>

            <div class="eb-woo-product-content-wrapper1">
                <div class="ml40px mt33px col-sm-8">
                    <?php if ( 'grid' === $layout && 'grid-preset-3' === $gridPreset ) { ?>
                    <p class="producttitle">
                        <a class="producttitle" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
                    </p>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <p class="producttitlewhite">
                        <a class="producttitlewhite" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
                    </p>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( 'grid' === $layout && 'grid-preset-3' === $gridPreset ) { ?>
                    <p class="productprice">
                        <?php if ( $showPrice ) { ?>
                            <p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
                            <p>Icon code<?php echo $product->get_icon(); ?></p>

                            <div style="display:block" class="mt-4 eb-woo-product-button-list"><?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <p class="productpricewhite">
                        <?php if ( $showPrice ) { ?>
                            <p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
                            <div style="display:block" class="mt-4 eb-woo-product-button-list"><?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'No product found', 'essential-blocks' ); ?></p>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to edit `woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php` file to fetch the meta key and the `get_prop` function doesn't work that way that you're assuming.

You can simply use [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function to fetch your meta key value for the product.

so you just need to replace `<p><?php echo $product->get_icon(); ?></p>`

with the below code:

```php
<p><?php echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'product_icon', true ); ?></p>
```